# Why are the relations in JPA not working?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

This is the Ingredient class

```
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED,force = true)
public class Ingredient {
    @Id
    private final String id;
    private final String name;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private final Type type;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "ingredient", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<IngredientRef> ingredientRefs = new ArrayList<>();


    public enum Type {
        WRAP, PROTEIN, VEGGIES, CHEESE, SAUCE
    }
}
```

This is TacoOrder class:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class TacoOrder implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private Date placedAt = new Date();
    @NotBlank(message = "Delivery name is required")
    private String deliveryName;
    @NotBlank
    private String deliveryStreet;
    @NotBlank(message = "City is required")
    private String deliveryCity;
    @NotBlank(message = "State is required")
    private String deliveryState;
    @NotBlank(message = "Zip Code is required")
    private String deliveryZip;
    @CreditCardNumber(message = "Invalid Credit Card Number")
    private String ccNumber;
    @Pattern(regexp = "^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])/20(2[3-9]|[3-9][0-9])$",message = "Must be of format MM/YYYY")
    private String ccExpiration;
    @NotNull
    @Digits(integer=3, fraction=0, message="Invalid CVV")
    private String ccCVV;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tacoOrder", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Taco> tacos = new ArrayList<>();
    public void addTaco(Taco taco) {
        this.tacos.add(taco);
    }
}
```

This is Taco class:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Taco {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private Date createdAt = new Date();

    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 5, message = "Name must be at least 5 characters long")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Ingredient> ingredients;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "taco_order_id")
    private TacoOrder tacoOrder;
}
```

This is the IngredientRef class which just shows the relation between Taco and which Ingredient was used in it:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class IngredientRef {
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ingredient_id")
    private Ingredient ingredient;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "taco_id")
    private Taco taco;
}
```

these are the logs

```
2023-08-31T02:30:35.257+05:30  INFO 16268 --- [io-8080-exec-10] com.example.tacohouse.OrderController    : Order submitted: TacoOrder(id=1, placedAt=Thu Aug 31 02:29:51 IST 2023, deliveryName=a, deliveryStreet=b, deliveryCity=b, deliveryState=b, deliveryZip=b, ccNumber=4417123456789113, ccExpiration=11/2024, ccCVV=111, tacos=[Taco(id=1, createdAt=Thu Aug 31 02:29:56 IST 2023, name=firstTaco, ingredients=[Ingredient(id=COTO, name=Corn Tortilla, type=WRAP, ingredientRefs=[])], tacoOrder=null, ingredientRefs=[]), Taco(id=2, createdAt=Thu Aug 31 02:30:02 IST 2023, name=secondTaco, ingredients=[Ingredient(id=CARN, name=Carnitas, type=PROTEIN, ingredientRefs=[])], tacoOrder=null, ingredientRefs=[]), Taco(id=3, createdAt=Thu Aug 31 02:30:07 IST 2023, name=thirdTaco, ingredients=[Ingredient(id=CHED, name=Cheddar, type=CHEESE, ingredientRefs=[]), Ingredient(id=JACK, name=Monterrey Jack, type=CHEESE, ingredientRefs=[])], tacoOrder=null, ingredientRefs=[])])
```

this is tables data in h2 console im using

```
ingredient table is fine
taco order table is fine
this is taco table
CREATED_AT      ID      TACO_ORDER_ID   NAME  
2023-08-31  02:29:51    1   null    firstTaco
2023-08-31  02:30:02    2   null    secondTaco
2023-08-31  02:30:07    3   null    thirdTaco
this is ingredient ref table
TACO_ID     INGREDIENT_ID  
(no rows, 0 ms)
```

I'm seeing IDs of tacoOrder and tacos created in the database but in the tacos table which has the foreign key of tacoOrder id it's null. also ingredient_ref table is empty. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you saving entities?

Comment: using h2,using data.sql file to preload data.mvc model that shows a 2 page website for designing taco and making order

Comment: I meant could you please share the code where you save this entities so that I can reproduce the issue?

Comment: in the controller i just save the tacoOrder which the forms gives in request and then log using ToString myself. the tacoOrder oobject comes with null and after i save it , it has ids. i also made tacos related to it by annotations but its still not sending tacoOrder id to tacos.
dont have an explicit definition of save method, was thinking if it would work if i just put
public interface OrderRepository extends CrudRepository<TacoOrder,Long> {
    @Transactional
    TacoOrder save(TacoOrder order);
}